# iOS How to detect data in variable Swift

Tags: ios, swift, variables

So i have issues with loading data, i have connection to **parse server**, and i *load data from Data Base*, this data are come to variable, i want detect when data in variable fulfill the label.

Maybe it's possible to use **do, catch**. But during 1 week solution was not founded.

My variables:

```
var userEmail = String()
var userPhone = String()
var userFullName = String()
```

Code to load data from parse:

```
let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User");
        query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.current()!.objectId!)
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (object, error) in
            if !(error != nil) {
                let user = PFUser.current()
                let login = user!["username"] as! String 
                let email = user!["email"] as! String
                let phone = user!["phoneNumber"] as! String 
                let fullName = user["fullname"] as? String 
                self.userEmail = email
                self.userPhone = phone
                self.userFullName = fullName
                self.userName = login
            }
        }
    }
```

Code to fulfil the labels:

```
func fulFillTextField() {
        fullNameLable.text = userFullName
        phoneNumberLable.text = userPhone
        emailLable.text = userEmail
        usernameLable.text = userName
}
```

Comment: No, you do not need `do catch` here. That being said what are you actually trying to achieve, what does "data in variable fulfill the label" mean and what does not work? Does you code crash, behave unexpected, fail to compile?

Comment: If i have not stable connection to network, data will load slow, code to load data located in viewDidLoad, if data are not loaded i have empty labels.

Comment: sooo? Show a loading indicator or something similar until the closure in `findObjectsInBackground` is called, in that closure do some UI work on the main thread to update the labels, dismiss some loading indicator, etc.

Comment: But if connection to network slowly, and my variables empty i display activitiIndicator, when i get data after some time, and some code detect data in variables, i dismiss the activitiIndicator and show label with data

Comment: @BestMoments What UI-items are you trying to initialise after query is finished? Show more code please.

Comment: @Roman Podymov Question was update

Comment: @BestMoments And where are you calling fulFillTextField ?

Comment: I call this method in viewDidLoad after query to DB

Comment: Call the fullFillTextField method once you have gotten a response from your backend and have set your userEmail etc properties. There's no point in calling it before you have gotten any data back if the text in those labels require existing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the function `fulFillTextField` one more time in the main thread after you received all data:

```
// The code inside handler for findObjectsInBackground
if !(error != nil) {

    let user = PFUser.current()
    let login = user!["username"] as! String 
    let email = user!["email"] as! String
    let phone = user!["phoneNumber"] as! String 
    let fullName = user["fullname"] as? String 
    self.userEmail = email
    self.userPhone = phone
    self.userFullName = fullName
    self.userName = login
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        fulFillTextField() // or self.fulFillTextField(), maybe fulFillTextField is a method of class and not a global function
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u, for help!